# application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool { } not called

Tags: ios, appdelegate, firebase-dynamic-links, deeplink, user-activity

I implemented Universal Link using Firebase Dynamic Links in my iOS app. Everything is working fine until app opens from background state i.e., `continue userActivity` method triggered and I handled navigations. But the problem here is, if I click any Deep Link while app is in terminated state, it is opening the app without navigating to particular screen, because the `continue userActivity` method not called so the navigation code not executing. Can you please help to figure out solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning `false` from `didFinishLaunching`. That prevents `continue` from being called.

Comment: It worked as you said, thanks for the answer. But I'm returning `ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)`. I checked that and I don't know why it is returning `false`. Can you please explain what's happening there?

Comment: If the launch options tell you that you have a user activity, you need to return `true`.